# Where is the gap in my validation rule using REGEX?

Tags: validation-rule, regular-expressions

I want to validate that Case Serial Numbers (origin !=web) are not less than 8 characters, never greater than 18, never = 11, 12, or 13 characters. AND they must be one of the REGEX statements below. I have a feeling there is at least one hole here. Can you help?

```
AND(
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Origin, 'Web')),
OR(
   LEN(SerialNumber__c) <8,
   LEN(SerialNumber__c) =11,
   LEN(SerialNumber__c) =12,
   LEN(SerialNumber__c) =13,
   LEN(SerialNumber__c) >18,
   NOT(
       OR(
          REGEX(SerialNumber__c, "[0-9]{8}" ),
          REGEX(SerialNumber__c, "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}" ),
          REGEX(SerialNumber__c, "[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}" ),
          REGEX(SerialNumber__c, "[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{7}" ),
          REGEX(SerialNumber__c, "[0-9]{10}" ),
          REGEX(SerialNumber__c, "[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{4}"),
          REGEX(SerialNumber__c, "[0-9]{14}"),
          REGEX(SerialNumber__c, "[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{7}"),
          REGEX(SerialNumber__c, "[0-9]{6}R-[0-9]{7}"),
          REGEX(SerialNumber__c, "[0-9]{7}R-[0-9]{7}"),
          REGEX(SerialNumber__c, "[0-9]{16}"),
          REGEX(SerialNumber__c, "[0-9]{8}R-[0-9]{7}"),
          REGEX(SerialNumber__c, "[0-9]{7}GR-[0-9]{7}"),
          REGEX(SerialNumber__c, "[0-9]{7}V[0-9]{1}-[0-9]{7}"), 
          REGEX(SerialNumber__c, "[0-9]{8}RS-[0-9]{7}")
         )
      )
  )
```

)

Comment: Looks fine to me. I mean, you didn't spell out every single rule, but it seems fine to me.

Comment: What input values should be matched and are not matched?

Comment: If you're sufficiently worried about this validation rule being correct, you could write a number of unit tests (in Apex) to verify its behavior. You'd have one test per input string (and those tests would be quick and easy to write).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Unfortunately there is a restriction on not using Apex for this. Must be declarative validation rule. The actual validation requirements can be explained like this: SN cannot be <8 characters nor 11, 12, or 13 characters. AND it cannot be >18 characters (it can be 10 characters though). AND if it is 8,9,10, 14, 15, 16, 17, or 18 characters is MUST be one of the REGEX formats. Hope this helps.

Comment: @DerekF  point was you could write an apex _testclass/testmethod_ and verify your regex until you get it right; the VR would stay declarative